# How to cancel next job in order after rsync

Tags: command-line, bash, rsync

If two jobs are entered into bash command line separated by semicolon:

```
$ job 1; job 2;
```

How do I cancel the second one? If I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, the first one will be canceled and 'job 2' would start, I just want to stop second job not to be executed. I tried atq, ps but no luck, with ps -ef I can see only 'job 1' but 'job 2' is not listed, so I can not get PID to use kill. I know I can use && instead of ; but it is too late now, I ran this command by accident on my server instead of my home PC and now I am trying to figure out how to prevent a disaster.

This problem is specific to rsync command followed by another command:

```
$ rsync ..... ; sudo shutdown -h now
```

Killing process by ID or killing it's parent will not work.

After several hours of testing, I isolated it to rsync, other commands I am able to terminate with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> in various orders, but not if they are after some commands like rsync or ping, I tried different Ubuntu versions, kernels, server without sudo user and I could reproduce it everywhere, best way to avoid this problem is to use && after rsync to execute following command only on success exitcode 0:

```
$ rsync .... && job 2
```

Comment: [Edit] your question an show the process tree.

Comment: It would be great if one of the answers could explain what is special about `rsync` that prevents Ctrl-C from working as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you miss something, When you run two commands seperated by `;` you can kill the both commands by the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

just to be sure try this command:

```
find / -name a ; ls /home
```

Then kill the above commands with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, this would kill both processes, you'll not list your home content. I.e, the next command will not run.

---

**UPDATE:** This also will be valid for your `rsync` command. Here my example:

```
$ rsync -avz /var/cache/apt/archives/ /tmp/backups/ ; sudo shutdown -h now

sending incremental file list
created directory /tmp/backups
./
authbind_1.2.0build3_amd64.deb
................
^Crsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c(549) [sender=3.0.9]
[sudo] password for user:
```

So as you see above When you run <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, this kill the first command and while starting shudown it will ask you for your `sudo` password, so you can now kill the second process using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> again.

---

**Update 2** As a hack for problem you can do:

- since you use passwordless `sudo` then make again your `sudo` ask for password by editing your sudoer file `sudo visudo`
- As a final step if nothing else works **and just a hack and it's not advisable** edit the `/sbin/shutdown` command to remove `+x` or just rename it to different name.

Comment: I have a rsync backup line followed by shutdown command: $ rsync ..... ; sudo shutdown -h now This for some reason does not end with Ctrl + C, I tried your example and it actually  does list the home on Ctrl + C, I have bash version 4.2.25, but I read an article about an hour ago, this is supposed to be this way from bash2 onward.

Comment: I think you should edit your question and add the above comment since to answer in general is some how different from specific question. for sure this will not  be used for your case

Comment: @mike Also I have bash v 4.2.25 and ctrl+c stops the second command just the example above, already tested it once again

Comment: Hi, for some reason after a restart your example works but I can not reproduce it on rsync followed by shutdown.

Comment: @Mike this also will work with rsync, you run rsync with sudo or without?

Comment: Hi, I am now testing other rsync syntax variations now, it executes the second command with and without sudo. My rsync version 3.0.9  protocol version 30. I tried different second command but it executes your ls example in the same way it did shutdown.

Comment: shutdown needs `sudo` it will stop to ask your password so you can kill it, check the update in my answer

Comment: I am sorry I wish I could do that here, my rsync command is rsync -avP --stats --human-readable --exclude=incomplete ... a lot of excludes, followed by specifying points from one server to another, I use this script for a long time to run backups between two servers,without any problem, just do not know how to stop it, I will update this after I will find the problem, but now I have only 30 minutes left.

Comment: @Mike your sudo is passwordless?

Comment: Yes, sudo is passwordless. $ cat /etc/sudoers ... mike ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

Comment: Ok, then make it with password, then you'll prmopt for sudo password, so you can kill it

Comment: Another hack is to move the +x from /sbin/shutdown or rename the command so it will not be executed, then  get the command back o default once you are in safe

Comment: I removed mike from sudoers, the second command will still get executed followed by ^Crsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c(549) [receiver=3.0.9]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 130) at rsync.c(549) [generator=3.0.9]

Comment: try the second comment above,

Comment: Thanks it worked, I renamed it and risked it and it worked. Now I will try to find the real cause, but this saved me a long trip to server room, thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25311/discussion-between-mike-and-maythux).

Answer (score 4):

Kill the **parent process** of job1 with `SIGKILL`.

Show the processes in a process tree, eg. with `htop` or `ps axf` and kill the ***parent process of job1*** and not job1 itself.

---

Install `htop` with

```
sudo apt-get install htop
```

---

**Downvoters, understand the answer before downvoting**

Comment: This will cause the disaster I was talking about, I tested this on my home PC, killing a process id will actually execute the second command, so this is not a good advice.

Comment: The parent process of job1 and not job1

Comment: @Mike This is valid solution also, What A.B means to kill the parent of job1 not job1 itself

Comment: I just tried to kill a parent job just now again so to make sure I test your theory, it shutdown again, does this really work on your machine? Your answer was my first choice this morning when I found out, but from my previous experience I tried if first on my PC and the second command just gets executed.

Comment: Indeed, this works, BUT: you must kill parent process with `SIGKILL`, not with `SIGTERM`, otherwise it won't be killed, and the second job will execute after the first one ends. BTW, you don't need `htop` or any other additional packages to view process tree, a simple `ps axf` will do.